# UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath is called in a wrong order

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and a problem I am facing is that sometime `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called in a wrong order.

We have 6 rows and one section in a table. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called in the order `(0, 2), (0, 3), (0,4), (0,5)`. So when the table loads, it shows the **3rd row** at the top. Now when I scroll down, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is again called with `(0,1)` and `(0,0)` and table jumps and shows **row 0** at the top.

**Update:** it seems that heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate was implemented and was incorrectly returning zero for the every indexPath. Although removing it solved the issue, the mystery remains why it was starting indexPath at (0,2). Any logical explanation?

Comment: can you share code ?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: this index path is of visible cells. When a cell becomes visible its indexpath is received in this delegate. Try to observe when you scroll the table view.

Comment: Code will be too big to paste, but can you point any reason why cellForRowAtIndexPath should not start at row 0 and jumps to row 2.

Comment: @Yusuf show your UI behaviour video.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate was implemented and was returning zero for the every indexPath. Although removing it solved the issue, the mystery remains why it was starting indexPath at (0,2)